# Is this a compiler bug, or a C language feature?

Tags: c, winapi, hyperlink, cl.exe

My environment is Windows XP SP3 + 'Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 14.00.50727.762 for 80x86'. The process is as follows:

> F:\workshop\vc8proj\console> type t.c

```
int main(void) {

    // Do some thing.
    {
        int i;
        {
            i = 3;
            goto abc111;
        }

        abc111:
    }
    return 0;
}
```

> F:\workshop\vc8proj\console> cl /MD t.c Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++
>   Optimizing Compiler Version 14.00.50727.762 for 80x86
>
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> t.c t.c(10) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
>
> F:\workshop\vc8proj\console>vim t.c
>
> F:\workshop\vc8proj\console>type t.c

```
int main(void) {
    // Do some thing.
    {
        int i;
        {
            i = 3;
            goto abc111;
        }

        abc111: 5201314;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

> F:\workshop\vc8proj\console> cl /MD t.c Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++
>   Optimizing Compiler Version 14.00.50727.762 for 80x86
>
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> t.c Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 8.00.50727.762 Copyright
>   (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> /out:t.exe t.obj
>
> F:\workshop\vc8proj\console>

Under the Linux operating system the same situation, too???

Answer (score 11):

It's a language feature. A label can only be part of a *labeled statement*, and the statement needs a terminating `;`. Just putting a semicolon behind the label suffices.

```
int main(void) {

    // Do some thing.
    {
        int i;
        {
            i = 3;
            goto abc111;
        }

        abc111: ;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

works too.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is a language feature. It is compulsory that there should be a statement to which we mentioned the label.

If there isn't any statement after the label then just put a ';' to terminate the statement or you can write a return statement after the label only.